# Migrate content types and contents from old drupal version to drupal 8

Tags: migrations

I'm working on a new drupal 8 website.
I have already a drupal 7 installation with severals content type (custom field image, date etc ...) and i dont know what is the best pratice to migrate thoses contents types to my new drupal 8 installation..
**Does someone know how to do that properly ?**
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this one, it pretty simple to migrate content types, fields, terms, users using below module:
https://drupalize.me/blog/201511/simple-drupal-7-drupal-8-migration

And this module does all the work:
https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade

Comment: Oops sorry for the bug ^^.
I know this module, but my question is : is this module can make a migration from a mysql to a postgre bdd ?
Regards,